# how to send value from dynamic form blazor to existing class?

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, mudblazor

I'm having trouble sending data in a dynamic form to a class, like the following example :
[image]

This is an example of a looped form, the problem is, I can't retrieve the changed value, so for example, I change the DPLK, then click update, the changed value in the DPLK input can't be retrieved.
So based on the UI above, every 1 input has 1 update button to change the value

this is for the code for the UI `DialogEditGlAccount.razor`

```
<MudDialog Class="mud-dialog-custom">
<DialogContent>
    <MudForm>
        <div class="row">
            @foreach (var data in _listFormGlEdit)
            {
                <div class="col-6 mb-3">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <label for="@data.Id">@data.Description</label>
                            <MudTextField T="string" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Margin="Margin.Dense" Clearable Value="data.GlAccount" @oninput="GetValueGlAccount" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 d-flex align-self-end">
                            <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Warning" Style="height:40px; border-radius:5;" @onclick="@(() => GlAccountUpdate(data.Id))">Update</MudButton>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </MudForm>
</DialogContent>
```

and this is for the created class `DialogEditGLAccount`

```
 public partial class DialogEditGLAccount : ComponentBase
{

    #region Override
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await GlAccountForm();
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Inject, Cascading

    [Parameter]
    public Guid ParamIdHeader { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string ModulName { get; set; }
    [Inject]
    private IArRemunerasiService _ArRemunerasiService { get; set; }
    [CascadingParameter]
    public MainLayout _MainLayout { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Field

    List<ArRemunerasiGlAccountResponse> _listFormGlEdit = new();
    private string _GlAccountEditValue;
    #endregion

    #region Method
    public async Task<ListResponse<ArRemunerasiGlAccountResponse>> GlAccountForm()
    {
        var result = new ListResponse<ArRemunerasiGlAccountResponse>();
        StateHasChanged();
        try
        {
            var token = await _MainLayout._AuthService.GetToken();
            result = await _ArRemunerasiService.ListGlAccount(ParamIdHeader, ModulName, 0, 0, token);
            _listFormGlEdit = result.List;
            if (!result.Succeeded)
                _MainLayout._Snackbar.ShowError(result.GetErrorMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _MainLayout._Snackbar.ShowError(ex.Message);
        }

        StateHasChanged();

        return result;
    }

    public async Task<StatusResponse> GlAccountUpdate(Guid GlAccountId)
    {
        var result = new StatusResponse();
        StateHasChanged();
        try
        {
            var token = await _MainLayout._AuthService.GetToken();
            result = await _ArRemunerasiService.EditGlAccount(GlAccountId, _GlAccountEditValue, token);
            if (!result.Succeeded)
                _MainLayout._Snackbar.ShowError(result.GetErrorMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _MainLayout._Snackbar.ShowError(ex.Message);
        }

        StateHasChanged();

        return result;
    }

    public void GetValueGlAccount(ChangeEventArgs changeEvent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((string)changeEvent.Value);
        _GlAccountEditValue = (string)changeEvent.Value;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

I have made the `GetValueGlAccount` method to retrieve the value but the result is always null

Comment: What does `ArRemunerasiGlAccountResponse` look like?  Can you put it (or abbreviated version) in your question.

Answer (score 0):

From the question :

```cs
<MudTextField ... @oninput="GetValueGlAccount" />
```

`MudTextField` don't have a event `OnInput`, then the method `GetValueGlAccount` is never called and the field `_GlAccountEditValue` remains empty.

What you try is :

```cs
<MudTextField ... @TextChanged="GetValueGlAccount" />

@
{
    public void GetValueGlAccount(string text)
    {
        _GlAccountEditValue = text;
    }
    ...
}
```

But there is a problem with this technique. If the user edit a field and click on the other's field button, the field is updated with the other field's text. Maybe it's wanted, but I'm going to assume not for the rest.

---

You want (I assume) when the user click the button pass to `EditGlAccount` the text input near the clicked button. Then you can do :

```cs
@foreach (var data in _listFormGlEdit)
{
    ...
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <label for="@data.Id">@data.Description</label>
        <MudTextField ... @bind-Value="data.GlAccount" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 d-flex align-self-end">
        <MudButton ... @onclick="@(() => GlAccountUpdate(data))">Update</MudButton>
    </div>
    ...
}

@code
{
    async Task GlAccountUpdate(ArRemunerasiGlAccountResponse glAccount)
    {
        ...
        result = await _ArRemunerasiService.EditGlAccount(glAccount.Id, glAccount.Description, token);
        ...
    }
}
```